# Как хранить объекты в List<T>? С#

Tags: c#

У меня есть абстрактный класс `Izdanie`, от которого наследуются классы `Kniga` и `Journal`. От `Kniga` наследуется класс `Uchebnik`.

Как мне правильно прописать List чтобы в нем можно было хранить объекты всех этих классов (Кроме абстрактного, само собой)? И как прописать вызов. Чтобы иметь возможность иметь доступ к полям и вызывать методы.

P.S. метод прописан в абстрактном классе и переопрелеляется в дочерних классах.

Answer (score 3):

> Как мне правильно прописать `List` чтобы в нем можно было хранить
>   объекты всех этих классов

Просто объявляете `List` для базового класса и всё. Тогда в него можно будет размещать объекты любого из классов наследников.

> И как прописать вызов. Чтобы иметь возможность иметь доступ к полям и
>   вызывать методы. P.S. метод прописан в абстрактном классе и
>   переопрелеляется в дочерних классах.

Это уже зависит от того, что включают в себя базовый класс и наследники и, что представляют собой эти методы.

В крайнем случае никто не запрещает объявить `List` для конкретного наследника или, на худой конец, привести типы.

Answer (score 1):

Объявление будет вида:

```
public void SomeMethod<T>(List<T> IzdList) where T : Izdanie
```

Пример использования:

```
class Program
{
    public static void ShowDescriptions<T>(List<T> IzdList) where T : Izdanie
    {
        foreach (var izdanie in IzdList)
            Console.WriteLine(izdanie.GetDescription());
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Izdanie> listIzdanie = new List<Izdanie>();

        Kniga k1 = new Kniga();
        k1.name = "Книга 1";
        k1.publisher = "Издатель 1";
        k1.year = 2017;

        listIzdanie.Add(k1);

        Uchebnik u1 = new Uchebnik();
        u1.name = "Учебник 1";
        u1.publisher = "Издатель 2";
        u1.year = 2016;
        u1.author = "Автор 1";

        listIzdanie.Add(u1);

        ShowDescriptions(listIzdanie);
    }
}

public abstract class Izdanie
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string publisher { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }

    public virtual string GetDescription()
    {
        return "Name: " + this.name + " Published: " + this.publisher + " in " + this.year.ToString();
    }
}

public class Kniga : Izdanie
{
    public override string GetDescription()
    {
        return "Name: " + this.name + " Published: " + this.publisher;
    }
}

public class Uchebnik : Izdanie
{
    public string author { get; set; }

    public override string GetDescription()
    {
        return "Name: " + this.name + " Published: " + this.publisher + " Author: " + this.author;
    }
}
```